# Fixing Hazus 2.2 Installation error?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation, hazus

I did a new install of ArcGIS 10.2.2 today along with an uninstall of Hazus 2.1 and an install of Hazus 2.2. The installation seemed to go fine but when I Open Hazus 2.2 I get  the following error:

```
Code = 800004003
Code Meaning: Invalid pointer
Source adtiRegion.DefineRegion.1
Description:
```

I can go through the region setup (with the same error appearing each time I hit the next button) Until I get to the State Selection Window, where I have no states to choose nor Counties to choose from in the following window.

I have no idea what is causing this as I followed the instructions included with the download to the letter.

As far as requirements go I am using the following software/hardware
Core i7 Processsor
Windows 7 ultimate (64 bit)
4 Gigs Ram
ArcGIS 10.2.2 Basic w/ Spatial Analyst extension

I have tried reinstalling Hazus 2.2 twice and the results have been the same both times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you have this figured out already. I'm running into the same issue and researching on this. Saw someone post on his linked in account that he had the issue and HAZUS support remote in using TeamViewer to tweak his SQL configuration to resolve the issue.

Comment: I marked this as correct as I think reaching out to Hazus support for any help is the way to go with this software. My workaround was actually to go build a new (and much better)machine and start over with fresh installs of everything from from the OS to Arc.I think the problems, in my case, were arising from leftover SQL components lying around after the uninstall. the leftover pieces were not playing well with the new Hazus SQl install.

Comment: Good to know you got it resolved. I couldn't follow your approach (at least not easily) due to my workplace IT policy. So I'm going to wait for HAZUS help desk to respond to my request.

Answer (score 0):

You may delete the database Hazus_model.mdf using SqlServer Management Studio and the error will disappear.I did this with Hazus 4.0.
best regards